# How to make a custom directive on how the markdown engine render a especific html tag?

Tags: markdown, hugo

ENV: Hugo static site generator

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
<figure>
  <table>...</table>
</figure>
```

What I'm getting:

```
<table>...<table>
```

Some markdown generators will render `table` tag inside `<figure></figure>` tag, but in case of hugo, in the standard it does not happen. How do I achieve this without having to mix `html` code inside the markdown file?

Comment: And what did you try to get `<table>...<table>`?

Comment: I tried with functions `replace` and `replaceRE` but no success until now. Following https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/how-i-extended-markdown-for-hugo/5983/5

Comment: getting close, trying to tweak the regex to stop the match on `</table>`

Answer (score 0):

After a while, this worked:

```
{{ $reIn1 := "<table>" }}
{{ $reOut1 := "<figure><table>" }}
{{ $reIn2 := "</table>" }}
{{ $reOut2 := "</table></figure>" }}
{{ $finalContent := .Content | replaceRE $reIn1 $reOut1 | replaceRE $reIn2 $reOut2 | safeHTML }}
{{ $finalContent }}
```

- Function `replace` does not work for this kind of job, only `replaceRE`.
- It is not well tested for false positives, but for what I need works well.

And why `table` inside another tag? Because of control of the `overflow-x`.